# wpf - commands , contextmenu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, command

How can I put the ContextMenu in a resource xaml file and bind it's commands to my current window's commands ?

Answer (score 4):

```
Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
```

It will use your current controls DataContext which should hold a command property "`SomeCommand`"

E.G.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ContextMenu x:Key="SomeContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Test Item" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in my ViewModel I would have the following property

```
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; set; }
```

And in my View.xaml

```
<Button ContextMenu="{StaticResource SomeContextMenu}">Test Button</Button>
```

Therefore the buttons DataContext is my ViewModel, therefore the SomeContextMenu which is in a ResourceDictionary in a external file binds to the same DataContext as the button, and therefore finds the SomeCommand within the ViewModel.